# Beginner C++ Nested Loop exercise problem

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, vector, nested-loops

I am trying to figure out what is wrong with my nested loop without receiving the answer to the exercise I'm working on. The initial error is that there is a comparison of signedness.

Prompt: Given a vector of integers named vec, find the sum of the product of all pairs of vector elements. Ex: {1,2,3}: (1x2)+(1x3)+(2x3) = 11. This needs to be stored in a variable called result.

The function is already set up and I am simply just writing the body.

My idea was that I was trying to grab the first element in the vector with the first for loop, and then used the second for loop to multiply the first element with the rest of the elements in the vector. I thought that the j = i+1 would allow me to avoid the value used in the first for loop and access the rest of the elements.

```
int result = 0;
int pair = 0;
for(int i = 0; i<=vec.size(); ++i){
    int num1 = vec.at(i);
        for(int j = i+1; j <= vec.size(); ++j){
            int num2 = vec.at(j);
            pair = num1 * num2;
            result = result + pair;
        }       
}
```

Comment: You don't explain what's your problem

Comment: the result of `num1*num2` is called `product`. Try to avoid standard names like `pair` because it's in `std::pair`

Comment: Hi, if you are clear with the answer please mark it also, so that other people may know about it.

Answer (score 0):

There are two errors

1. A vector's size is an **unsigned** quantity, specifically the type is `size_t` so that is the type you should use for your `i` variable. That will fix the signed/unsigned comparison warning.
2. Vectors are indexed from **zero**. So the valid indexes for a vector go from zero to one less than the size of the vector. So `i<=vec.size()` is incorrect.

Putting both those fixes together your loop should look like this

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < vec.size(); ++i) {
```

Similar issues with the `j` loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
int result = 0;
int pair = 0;
for(size_t i = 1; i <= vec.size(); ++i){               // if you want it 1 indexed
    int num1 = vec.at(i-1);
        for(size_t j = i+1; j <= vec.size(); ++j){
            int num2 = vec.at(j-1);
            pair = num1 * num2;
            result = result + pair;
        }       
}
```

```
int result = 0;
int pair = 0;
for(size_t i = 0; i < vec.size(); ++i){               // if you want it 0 indexed
    int num1 = vec.at(i);
        for(size_t j = i+1; j < vec.size(); ++j){
            int num2 = vec.at(j);
            pair = num1 * num2;
            result = result + pair;
        }       
}
```

Explanation given by @john is enough to answer your query. Also you should be careful about variable names as suggested by @phuclv.
Hope it is fine now for you.